# Pandas, for each unique value in one column, get unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each row contains various meta-data pertaining to a single Reddit comment (e.g. author, subreddit, comment text).

I want to do the following: for each author, I want to grab a list of all the subreddits they have comments in, and transform this data into a pandas dataframe where each row corresponds to an author, and a list of all the unique subreddits they comment in.

I am currently trying some combination of the following, but can't get it down:

Attempt 1:

```
group = df['subreddit'].groupby(df['author']).unique()
list(group)
```

Attempt 2:

```
from collections import defaultdict
subreddit_dict  = defaultdict(list)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    author = row['author']
    subreddit = row['subreddit']
    subreddit_dict[author].append(subreddit)

for key, value in subreddit_dict.items():
    subreddit_dict[key] = set(value)

subreddit_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(subreddit_dict, 
                            orient = 'index')
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example DF and expected output?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here are two strategies to do it. No doubt, there are other ways.

Assuming your dataframe looks *something* like this (obviously with more columns):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'author':['a', 'a', 'b'], 'subreddit':['sr1', 'sr2', 'sr2']})

>>> df
  author subreddit
0      a       sr1
1      a       sr2
2      b       sr2
...
```

**SOLUTION 1: groupby**

More straightforward than solution 2, and similar to your first attempt:

```
group = df.groupby('author')

df2 = group.apply(lambda x: x['subreddit'].unique())

# Alternatively, same thing as a one liner:
# df2 = df.groupby('author').apply(lambda x: x['subreddit'].unique())
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
author
a    [sr1, sr2]
b         [sr2]
```

The author is the index, and the single column is the *list of all subreddits* they are active in (this is how I interpreted how you wanted your output, according to your description).

If you wanted the subreddits each in a separate column, which might be more useable, depending on what you want to do with it, you could just do this after:

```
df2 = df2.apply(pd.Series)
```

Result:

```
>>> df2
          0    1
author          
a       sr1  sr2
b       sr2  NaN
```

**Solution 2: Iterate through dataframe**

you can make a new dataframe with all unique authors:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'author':df.author.unique()})
```

And then just get the list of all unique subreddits they are active in, assigning it to a new column:

```
df2['subreddits'] = [list(set(df['subreddit'].loc[df['author'] == x['author']])) 
    for _, x in df2.iterrows()]
```

This gives you this:

```
>>> df2
  author  subreddits
0      a  [sr2, sr1]
1      b       [sr2]
```

Comment: Internally, what is happening with this line: `df2 = group.apply(lambda x: x['subreddit'].unique())` Does "x" represent all the rows in the dataframe of a given author?

Comment: It's an anonymous function that is applied to each group in your `groupby`: it gets all the unique values in the `subreddit` column for each group (i.e. each author). `x` is simply the group, so yeah, essentially, the subset of your original dataframe with a given author.

Comment: @sacuL Is there a way to get ALL values in the `subreddit` column instead of just the unique ones?

Comment: @Python_newbieash, IIUC, `group = df.groupby('author')` `df2 = group.apply(lambda x: list(x['subreddit']))` would be a quick and dirty way to do it

Comment: @sacuL Thanks! That's quite helpful!

Answer (score 9):

By using sacul's sample data

```
df['subreddit'].groupby(df['author']).unique().apply(pd.Series)
Out[370]: 
          0    1
author          
a       sr1  sr2
b       sr2  NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

Using groupby.agg() "aggrgeate" function:

*

> DataFrameGroupBy.agg(arg, *args, **kwargs): aggregate using one or
> more operations over the specified axis. Function to use for
> aggregating the data. If a function, must either work when passed a
> DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply

- 

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 6, 9], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'red', 'white']}, columns=['numbers', 'colors'])
```

[image]

---

```
df.groupby('colors', as_index=True).agg({'numbers' : {"unique" : lambda x: set(x),
                                                      "nunique" : lambda x : len(set(x))}})
```

[image]

Comment: Great illustration. You saved my day, thanks!