# Extract the items visited to date from individual visit records dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a large pandas dataframe where every row corresponds to a date-stamped visit. I need  a new dataframe of dates and the set of items visited to date.

```
# original df
visit_records = [['01-01-2020', 'c'], ['01-02-2020', 'b'], ['01-02-2020', 'c'], ['01-04-2020', 'a'], ['01-05-2020', 'd']]
df = pd.DataFrame(visit_records, columns=["date", "location"])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


        date location
0 2020-01-01        c
1 2020-01-02        b
2 2020-01-02        c
3 2020-01-04        a
4 2020-01-05        d
```

desired output (order does not matter in the items lists):

```
        date visited_to_date
0 2020-01-01                      [c]
1 2020-01-02                   [c, b]
2 2020-01-04                [c, b, a]
3 2020-01-05             [c, b, a, d]
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979604/pandas-for-each-unique-value-in-one-column-get-unique-values-in-another-column) but it returns the items visited for every date, and not all that have been visited to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best, but `apply` and `cumsum` would do:

```
df['visited_to_date'] = (df.location
   .drop_duplicates()               # only look at unique values
   .apply(lambda x: [x])            # change each value into a list
   .cumsum()                        # list cumsum
)
df[df['visited_to_date'].notnull()]
```

Output:

```
        date location visited_to_date
0 2020-01-01        c             [c]
1 2020-01-02        b          [c, b]
3 2020-01-04        a       [c, b, a]
4 2020-01-05        d    [c, b, a, d]
```

Comment: didn't know you could apply `cumsum` with lists like that! Nice

Comment: a bit hard to follow, but it does works. With this now, I tried `df.groupby(by='date').apply(lambda x: x['location'].unique())` and then a cumsum like here, but I failed to get it work.

Comment: Grouping by `date` do you no good since it won't see duplicates across the dates.

Comment: this also works and it's easier to read, maybe a bit redundant: `df.location.apply(list).cumsum().apply(set).apply(list)`