# Iterate over rows for unique skiers

Tags: python, pandas

I am a PhD student in motor skill learning and I'm the phase where I am trying to plan how I will structure and analyse my data. I would really appreciate if you could provide me some input as to how I should go about:

[My data][1]

The data collection has not started yet but we have run a pilot to see how the data looks like.

In this dataset, there are 12 skiers (BIB column) that have completed 12 runs (the finish columns). The first three runs is a straight-gliding condition where the skiers' ski a course straight down (no slalom turns made). The rest of the runs is a condition where the skiers make turns. What we want to do in this study is express how good the skiers are to pump compared to straight-gliding. To compute this we would like to take the average of two best runs in the FINISH column that is dummy coded as 1. And then divide this by the straight gliding run (dummy coded as 0). What is the best way to do this?

I am using python and pandas.

Best

Comment: Might want to try and re-add your data.

Comment: Data is not visible, can you re-add that image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979604/pandas-for-each-unique-value-in-one-column-get-unique-values-in-another-column