# Python/Pandas - Identify unique values in one column which match the exact same unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still new to working with dataframes and am trying to identify unique values in one column which have the exact same unique values in another column. For example, if element 'a' in column 'A' has unique values of 'x', 'y', and 'z' in column 'B', how do I find the other elements in column 'A' which also have unique values of 'x', 'y', and 'z' in column 'B'?

The solution in this post got me halfway there but still requires manual analysis to retrieve this information: [Pandas, for each unique value in one column, get unique values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979604/pandas-for-each-unique-value-in-one-column-get-unique-values-in-another-column)

Applying this solution to an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'name': ['John', 'Jane', 'John', 'Bill', 'Sue', 'Fred', 'Bill'],
'response': [23, 29, 21, 21, 34, 18, 23]})

print(df1.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: 
x['response'].sort_values().unique()).reset_index())
```

Produces the following result:

```
   name         0
0  Bill  [21, 23]
1  Fred      [18]
2  Jane      [29]
3  John  [21, 23]
4   Sue      [34]
```

I would like to find a solution to identify Bill and John had identical responses.

Thanks everyone!

P.S. Any advice on how to rename the '0' column in the output would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much got it, just have to mod the column values a little, so you won't get an error for the next iteration similar to your first.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'name': ['John', 'Jane', 'John', 'Bill', 'Sue', 'Fred', 'Bill'],
'response': [23, 29, 21, 21, 34, 18, 23]})

df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x['response'].sort_values().unique()).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'response'})

#consolidate values while keeping seperator, so you can iterate again error free
df.response = [str(list(x)) for x in df.response]
```

out

```
|    | name   | response   |
|---:|:-------|:-----------|
|  0 | Bill   | [21, 23]   |
|  1 | Fred   | [18]       |
|  2 | Jane   | [29]       |
|  3 | John   | [21, 23]   |
|  4 | Sue    | [34]       |
```

Now do one more iteration, similar to before

```
df.groupby('response').apply(lambda x: x['name'].sort_values().unique()).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'name'})

|    | response   | name            |
|---:|:-----------|:----------------|
|  0 | [18]       | ['Fred']        |
|  1 | [21, 23]   | ['Bill' 'John'] |
|  2 | [29]       | ['Jane']        |
|  3 | [34]       | ['Sue']         |
```